# Is it possible to parametrize all smooth functions by 1 continuous parameter?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Is it possible to parametrize all smooth or analytic functions by 1 continuous parameter? Ie a function f(x,t) such that if g(x) is some smooth function then f(x,t) for some t is the function g(x). Can f be smooth on its domain?

Comment: Functions like $g(x)=f(x,x)+1$  seem problematic.

Comment: The function space is infinite-dimensional. For instance, analytic functions are determined by their power series, and you have an infinite number of coefficients which you can vary.

Comment: lulu's counter-example answers the question of can $f$ be smooth. No, it cannot. But it is indeed possible to define a continuous surjection from $\Bbb R$ into the space of all analytic functions on $\Bbb R^n$ for any finite $n$, under any of the common topologies. Since this space has only countably infinite dimension, it is possible to adapt the construction of space-filling curves to this situation. This sidesteps lulu's counter-example, as $g$ will definitely not be analytic, and thus not in the space being filled.